# Error : When Using SqlDependency Without Providing an Options Value

Tags: c#, sql-server, service-broker

I am working on query notification. I have created **Queue, Service** and **Route** in my Database. I am accessing my Database on **Network** by **IP Address**, so i created a **Route** in **Sql Server** like this..

```
ALTER ROUTE [NotificationMessagesRoute]   
WITH  SERVICE_NAME  = N'MyNotificationService' ,  
ADDRESS  = N'TCP://myIPAddress:PortNo' --
```

on FrontEnd it have used SqlDependency like this..

```
SqlDependency dependency = new SqlDependency(command), "Service=MyNotificationService;local database=Test", int.MaxValue);
```

Its working Perfectly, if i am using **Local Connection String** and also **Route** in **Sql Server** as **Local**, but if i access DB on my organizations **local Network**, it do not show me **notification** on **new Insertion**.

I have also used **SqlDependency** object as below, but it gives me below **Error**.

```
 SqlDependency dependency = new SqlDependency(command);
```

***Error** : When using SqlDependency without Providing an options value, SqlDependency.Start() must be called prior to execution of a command added to the SqlDependency instance.*

Plz Help...

Answer (score 7):

Add start the dependency in Startup class

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDependency.Start(ConnectionString);
```

Answer (score 5):

You need to set `ENABLE_BROKER` for the database by running the query below:

```
ALTER DATABASE [your_database_name] SET ENABLE_BROKER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE;
```

Answer (score 1):

`SqlDependency` works only locally, because it goes ahead and deploys target service, queue and activated procedure for you. If you want to deploy in a remote scenario you will need use the more basic [`SqlNotificationRequest`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sql.sqlnotificationrequest.aspx). You will have to deploy the required destination service yourself, in app. See [Using SqlNotificationRequest to Subscribe to Query Notifications](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190270%28v=sql.105%29.aspx).

I hope you do understand that a remote route expects at its destination another SQL Server instance, not your app, and you must properly set up endpoint and dialog security, see [Service Broker Communication Protocols](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms166061%28v=sql.105%29.aspx). It is very unlikely that you need a remote route for your scenario.

Comment: I want to access my database on my Local Network, so what should be the effective solution according to you for Notifications..

Comment: The notification should be local. Read [here](http://rusanu.com/2006/06/17/the-mysterious-notification/) to understand how it works.