# Cannot receive change notifications using SqlDependency

Tags: c#, service-broker, sqldependency

I'm using Sql Server Service Broker for the first time, trying to subscribe to notifications whenever there are changes in a particular table. I'm getting the following exception when I call `command.ExecuteReader()`:

> System.InvalidOperationException : When using SqlDependency without providing an options value, SqlDependency.Start() must be called prior to execution of a command added to the SqlDependency instance.

I've created a test to reproduce the scenario (leaving out a few of the related methods for brevity), as follows:

```
private string _queueName = "EventsToPublishChangeMessages";
    private bool _notificationReceived;

    [Test]
    public void WhyDoesExceptionIndcateSqlDependencyStartHasNotBeenCalledPriorToCommandExecuteReader()
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"canRequestNotifications: {CanRequestNotifications()}"); // returns true
        var connectionString = GetConnectionString();
        var started = SqlDependency.Start(connectionString, _queueName); // exception below seems to suggest that I haven't started the SqlDependency. Am I doing something wrong on this line?
        Console.WriteLine($"Started:{started}"); // returns true
        var connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
        var command = new SqlCommand("SELECT Id, EventType, [Data], Created FROM dbo.EventsToPublish", connection);
        var sqlDependency = new SqlDependency(command);
        sqlDependency.OnChange += OnChange;
        connection.Open();

        // The following line causes the exception:
        // System.InvalidOperationException : When using SqlDependency without providing an options value, SqlDependency.Start() must be called prior to execution of a command added to the SqlDependency instance.
        // But you can see that I *did* call SqlDependency.Start() above.
        using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
        {
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                Process(reader);
            }
        }

        TryToTriggerANotification(connectionString);
        Thread.Sleep(5000); // ie. wait a few seconds to ensure notification-handling background thread has had a chance to complete.

        Assert.That(_notificationReceived, Is.True);
    }

    private void TryToTriggerANotification(string connectionString)
    {
        using (var connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            using (var command = new SqlCommand(
                    "INSERT INTO dbo.EventsToPublish(Id, EventType, [Data], Created) VALUES(newid(), 'StackOverflowQuestionTest', '', GETDATE())",
                    connection))
            {
                connection.Open();
                command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }
    }

    private void OnChange(object sender, SqlNotificationEventArgs e)
    {
        _notificationReceived = true;
    }

    private bool CanRequestNotifications()
    {
        try
        {
            var sqlClientPermission = new SqlClientPermission(PermissionState.Unrestricted);
            sqlClientPermission.Demand();
            return true;
        }
        catch
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

I've issued the following SQL queries to try to get a better understanding of what's happening:

```
select * from sys.service_queues -- can see my EventsToPublishChangeMessages queue
select is_broker_enabled from sys.databases where database_id=db_id() -- returns 1
select * from sys.dm_qn_subscriptions -- returns nothing
select * from sys.transmission_queue -- returns nothing
```

Has anyone got any ideas on what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19155819/error-when-using-sqldependency-without-providing-an-options-value help? Or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27411100/sqldependency-startconnectionstring-return-every-time-false?

Comment: @mjwills The answer in the second link helped resolve the issue, ie. using the SqlDependency constructor with the options argument. If you want to post as an answer instead of a comment, I'd be happy to mark that as the answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message says:

> `SqlDependency.Start()` must be called prior to execution of a command added to the SqlDependency instance

The help on [`SqlDependency.Start`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldependency.start(v=vs.110).aspx) states:

> Starts the listener for receiving dependency change notifications.
>
> ...
>
> Ensure that Start is only called once per AppDomain

So place a `Start()` call somewhere in your app startup. Since this looks like a test method, perhaps in a [`[ClassInitialize]`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.unittesting.classinitializeattribute.aspx)  decorated method.

Comment: There was a little bit more to it than this, but definitely part of the problem was that I was calling SqlDependency.Start() more than once per AppDomain - in my original case I had two tests calling the same system-under-test that contained the SqlDependency.Start() call. 

For the example test written above, I also had to use the constructor overload that takes options and timeout, and specify options of "SERVICE=[my-service-name]" to fix this issue.

Comment: @remus Small question: SqlDependency.Start() calls ones on AppDomain start.  Does in make sense to call SqlDependency.Stop() before SqlDependency.Start()?

Comment: @Natalya please ask as a separate question

Comment: @RemusRusanu can you answer this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45478012/ensure-sqldependency-was-stopped